# get list of removable media in c (on linux)

Tags: c, linux

I was trying to make a program to copy files from the documents folder on my Linux machine into the documents folder onto a USB with Windows on it. So far, it only creates files without copying any actual data to them, but that's not the problem I'm trying to solve right now. The code looks like this (there are no real errors, more information is written under the code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{
    DIR *folder;
    struct dirent *entry;
    int files = 0;

    folder = opendir("/home/ubuntumate/Documents");
    if(folder == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to read directory");
        return(1);
    }

    while( (entry=readdir(folder)) )
    {
        if(entry->d_type == DT_REG)
        {
            files++;
            
            char newfilename[100];
            snprintf(newfilename, sizeof(newfilename), "/media/ubuntumate/7494348594344C3C/Users/John/Documents/%s", entry->d_name);
            FILE *clone = fopen(newfilename, "w");
            fclose(clone);
        }
    }

    closedir(folder);

    return(0);
}
```

You may have noticed that I hard-coded the media's location, including both the username and the media's id. (my username is "ubuntumate" because I'm on a virtual machine running Ubuntu MATE). The question I'm asking is how do i get a list of all the medias attached to the machine, so that this program can still work with a different user, and on a different USB that also contains windows?

Comment: Are you sure that `100` is large enough to hold the calculated filename? You should check that `snprintf` doesn't silently crop your filename. You should also check that `fopen` doesn't fail. To avoid the problem of buffer size, you could use the `openat` family of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether a block device is removable under the `sys` hierarchy. E.g. something like

```
$ stat /dev/sdc|grep Device
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 347         Links: 1     Device type: 8,20
```

From here you see the device is major number 8, minor 20 (in hex). Then check

```
$ cat /sys/dev/block/8\:32/removable 
0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was trying to get a list using C rather than bash.

Comment: @personthehuman: You're welcome. The point of the answer was not to provide a ready solution, but to demonstrate the concepts without getting bogged down in the details of how to implement it in any particular programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found an answer. I can just list all the folders in the media/[username] folder. There are a lot of tutorials on getting the username so that one wont be a problem, cuz i can just search it up.

Comment: Note that this is dependent on services like `gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor` (on gnome, other desktop environments probably have something equivalent) that is started as part of a GUI session. On a headless machine you can't trust that removable devices will show up by themselves under `/media`.

Comment: The application i'm making wont have a problem with that because i'm distributing it with the operating system as an ISO. it's main purpose will be to do some changes to a hard drive on another computer.